# What is the licence in salesforce and How company buy licence?

Tags: community, licenses

[image]

we have few licenses as shown in picture. I would like to know that for every company is having same licenses or different licenses? and What is 60000 for partner community login. Is that limit of 60000 users or what? Can anyone please make me understand about this licenses.

Comment: I recommend you reach out to your Salesforce Account Executive who can help explain what each license means and how you got them if you're looking for a definitive answer specific to your org.

Answer (score 4):

There are a wide range of different licence types available for Salesforce, see the documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_understanding_license_types.htm). As you have Saleforce Communities, the details of the licence types for that product are [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US).

The number of licences available to any specific Salesforce customer will vary on what they have purchased and will not be the same across different customers orgs. The types of licence required depend on how the Saleforce customer uses the system.

The licence purchase is through usually dealing with an Account Executive working for Salesforce when you have the numbers of licences shown. Small companies may end up purchasing directly just using a credit card, but that would normally be for a very low number of licences where no discounting may apply, e.g. 5 users on Group Edition.

The 60,000 Customer Community Login is the number of unique logins that users on that licence type can make per month. It is not restrictive of the amount of logins per user on that licence type make each month, but is an upper limit to the number that can be made by the Community members without incurring any additional licencing fees for the Salesforce Org.

Your organisation has 1,411 actual Salesforce user licences, with 20 remaining to be allocated to users.

Comment: Hi Dave good Knowledge share. Can you please make me understand about this line:                                                                                                                                      The number of licences available to any specific Salesforce customer will vary on what they have purchased and will not be the same across different customers orgs

Comment: Each customer's instance of Salesforce is called an organisation or Org. When a customer buys licences from Salesforce there is no fixed number, instead they will buy as many of the different types of licences they need, e.g as a consultant I have worked for a customer that had 15,000 Saleforce licences and other customers that had maybe 100 or 200 licences depending on how big the company was and how many people within it needed to use Salesforce.

Comment: It means you're paying for 20 seats which you are not currently using. That's actually a lot in most orgs that I have worked on.

Comment: @AdrianLarson They are also paying for 1284 UNUSED Force.com licenses (Salesforce Platform)